# undefined method `id' for 0:Fixnum when destroy

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I'm trying to destroy a record in the database, but I'm getting an error I do not understand:

> undefined method `id' for 0:Fixnum in the view

Here is my view:

```
<%= form_for(:subject, :url => { :action => 'destroy' , :id => @subject.id }) do  %>
    <h2> Are you sure you want to delete <%= @subject.name %> ? </h2>
    <div class="form-buttons">
    <%= submit_tag("DELETE") %>
<% end %>
```

Controller actions:

```
  def delete
    @subject = Subject.delete(params[:id])
  end

  def destroy
    @subject = Subject.delete(params[:id]).destroy
    redirect_to(:action=> 'index')
  end
```

Comment: can you post the full backtrace?

Comment: It should be `find` for both actions, instead of `delete`.

Comment: What is the name of the view file and to which action it is appended to?

Comment: @potashin thanks , its solved now.

Comment: @BaderHAlRayyes : I've posted an answer

Comment: @potashin , sorry, thought you will not, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Controller actions:

```
def delete
  @subject = Subject.find(params[:id]).delete
end

def destroy
  @subject = Subject.find(params[:id]).destroy
  redirect_to(:action=> 'index')
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Contrary to the comments etc, you have the [correct syntax](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Relation/delete), but a little issue:

```
def destroy
    @subject = Subject.delete params[:id]
    redirect_to :index
end
```

---

Your `delete` action is a [Red Herring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_herring) and should be removed from the controller (its syntax is correct but it's not used).

The above code *should* work. Your error was that you were calling `destroy` (an *instance* method) on an object which doesn't support it. If you wanted to use `.destroy`, you'd have to use it on an instance of the `Subject` class:

```
@subject = Subject.find params[:id]
@subject.destroy
```

As you have it in my code above, the `Subject.delete params[:id]` method will work as it's a *class* method. You must know, though, that `.delete` doesn't invoke any callbacks.